# Eclipse: No repository found at xyz (ProvisionException)

Tags: eclipse

As of today, my own Eclipse update site has stopped working - without any modifications to the files on the server.

I got notified by two independent users that Eclipse Juno cannot access the site anymore and was able to reproduce the problem myself, with my Windows/Indigo installation at work and Linux/Juno on my home PC.

The update site is http://eclipse.schedenig.name/

Eclipse gives the following error message:

```
No repository found at http://eclipse.schedenig.name/.
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
```

With the following stack trace written to the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2013-07-08 22:51:51.486
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://eclipse.schedenig.name/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicRefreshRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryManager.refreshRepository(ArtifactRepositoryManager.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.RepositoryManipulationPage$21.run(RepositoryManipulationPage.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 1000 2013-07-08 22:51:51.486
!MESSAGE No repository found at http://eclipse.schedenig.name/.
```

The odd thing is that the stack trace doesn't give a reason *why* no repository was found. The even odder thing is that *it still works fine in my Kepler installation!*

I've tried moving the repository around. Eclipse has no problems reading it from a local directory via a file:// URL, but regardless on what domain or server I put it (I tried both a different domain and my LAN Apache HTTP), Juno refuses to see the repository.

The exact same site still worked when I tried it myself last time, on July 1st right after my latest update to it. Since then the files haven't changed. All other update sites in my settings still work fine.

Google mostly yields results to proxy settings. I'm not using a proxy at home, my browser has no problems accessing the site with a direct connecting, and more importantly, Kepler has no problem seeing the update site with no proxy settings.

Comment: And suddenly, all by itself, it started working again, for me and others. Apparently there's some external source that has an effect on Eclipse dealing with my update site. I'm leaving this question open in the hope that someone can explain what caused this.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly exactly the same problem. In my case, the problem seemed to be the SSL certificate with low Java version.

For the next person with same symptoms:

- Check
  Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform.
- If you see any errors there, edit the entry with errors. In my case, Eclipsed seemed to have failed to get anything from some update sites. Double clicking on the entries yielded SSLHandshakeException.

If you have the same problem - possible solutions:

- If you have any power on any update sites - as in my case - check the SSL certificate (-> e.g. conatct system administrator).
- If you can switch to higher Java version - try.

Hope this helps